# Cutting transparent rectangle using canvas from filled rectangle Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-custompainter

I pin the picture of how it should looks like. I was trying ti use Cnavas, because as I inderstood such things can't be done by simple widget. So I have a question, how can I extract rectangle from this filled rectangle? I saw solution like this:

```
class TransparantRectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.blue;
    canvas.drawPath(
      Path.combine(
        PathOperation.difference,
        Path()
          ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBR(100, 100, 300, 300, Radius.elliptical(x: 10, y: 15))),
        Path()
          ..addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(100, 100, 100, 100)
          ..close(),
      ),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the `fromLTRBR`,

> Construct a rounded rectangle from its left, top, right, and bottom edges,
> and the same radius in each corner.

And `fromLTRB`

> Construct a rectangle from its left, top, right, and bottom edges.

It is better to use `size` rather than hard coded value.

If you want round corner, use `addRRect`,
`quadraticBezierTo` or `relativeQuadraticBezierTo` etc.

```dart
class TransparentRectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.red;

    final Path path1 = Path()
      ..addRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBR(
            0, 0, size.width, size.height, const Radius.elliptical(10, 15)),
      );

    final Path path2 = Path()
      ..addRect(
        Rect.fromLTRB(0, size.height / 2, size.width / 2, size.height),
      );

    canvas.drawPath(
      Path.combine(PathOperation.difference, path1, path2),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TransparentRectanglePainter oldDelegate) =>
      this != oldDelegate;
}
```

[image]

Visit flutter.dev to learn more about [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget.

Comment: thanks you so much, you are life saver. I really know so a little about CustomPaint, because I have never used it before

Comment: Glad to help you out, You can also article on medium and youtube, but best is flutter.dev IMO.